# Tax in India and UK

Tags: united-kingdom, india, state-income-tax, salary

I came to the UK in March 2019. Due to other formalities, my bank account was opened in April 2019. So in March 2019 my Indian salary got credited in an Indian bank account after tax deductions.

In April 2019, my salary was placed in a UK bank account and the balanced UK part on March salary as arrears.

So my April UK salary has April India salary, April UK allowances along with March UK allowance as arrears and March India salary as deductions.

UK tax deductions are beyond my calculations in April payslip.

So my question is:
Is there any tax applicable on March arrears? If yes is it because of the fact that it is credited in April? Isn’t the double taxation on the same amount?

/Abhi

Comment: For those of you that don't know what "arrears" is -  "money that is owed and should have been paid earlier."

Comment: Is this income from a British or Indian employer? And for work you performed in India or the UK? (The _location of the bank_ is much less important than the source and reason for the payment).

Comment: Employer is Indian based multinational in UK and work performed in UK

Comment: this seems incredibly tricky  :/